# c# - How to use SAPI to do speech to text?

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, sapi

I want to learn the SAPI api for c# to do speech to text recognition.

I can't find any tutorials. Can anyone show me where an example is or can show it here?

It needs to have aupport to get the speech from a webcam mic.

Thanks.

Comment: There's just no point to this.  Use the .NET SpeechRecognitionEngine class, it is a wrapper for SAPI.

Answer (score 2):

API documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(v=vs.85).aspx

Using SAPI in C#: http://windowscoding.com/blogs/blake/archive/2006/11/01/How-to-use-Microsofts-Speech-API-in-a-managed-application.aspx

You're right, there aren't many/any tutorials.  But there's the basics - and there are plenty of C/C++ resources.  Give it a go and if you have a *specific question*, that's a far better thing to ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for those resources, but I went through them before, but don't understand how to use it. I also don't see any example codes either.

Comment: You can't ask for much more than an API with documentation.  With that, you can do anything.  Which *specific* problem in particular have you tried to solve but not been able to?

Comment: I am trying to solve the task of getting a speech from a mic and converting it to text using the api, but can't see any documentation for that. I'm not sure how to get more specific...

Comment: That's like saying "I'm trying to build a house but I can't find a video telling me how".. obviously you can get a lot more specific.  Do some research... The API documentation above plus Google are equivalent to a library.  Here's a specific question example: "I'm using method X of interface Y, but it doesn't seem to correctly fire event Z: why is that?".

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late for this question, but hopefully it can help people later. I want to do the same thing recently, using micphone as voice input, then sapi do the recognition part. I actually found the example code in sapi's own documents, which is written by C#. As default install location, it should be in the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Docs. It works pretty well.